# How to disable click event in seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
const arrowright = document.querySelector(".fa-arrow-right"); //this is font-icon
const arrowleft = document.querySelector(".fa-arrow-left"); // this is font-icon
```

first scenario is when i click the arrowright with click event then the arrowleft will disable in 3 to 5 seconds then after 3  to 5 seconds when i click the second button which is the arrowleft then the next one will be disable is the arrowright with 3 to 5 seconds then it must be repeating scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

On click of a button , add a disabled attribute to the other one that must be disabled and run a setTimeOut function that remove the added class after 3 or 5 sec

https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could map a disable function to each button's `onclick` and pass an identifier to determine which button should be disabled. If you use setTimeout, you can then enable the button again after that time.

```js
function disable(buttonId) {
  let button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
  
  button.disabled = true;
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    button.disabled = false
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#left, #right {
  font-size: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="disable('right')" id="left">&#9664;</button>
<button onclick="disable('left')" id="right">&#9654;</button>
```